# Total number of electric field lines coming out of a proton?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I have to calculate the total number of electric field lines through a proton. I tried using Gauss' Law, i.e, $$\phi = \oint\boldsymbol E.d\boldsymbol s = {\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}} $$   $$So, \phi = {\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}} $$

$$ \textrm{Therefore}, \phi = \frac{1.6\times10^{-19}}{8.854\times10^{-12}}$$, as $q=1.6\times10^{-19}C$ and
$\epsilon_0 = 8.854\times10^{-12}C^2N^{-1}m^{-2}$.

But the answer is $0.18\times10^{-7}$ or something like that. How can that be the number of field lines? How can that be the number of anything? I mean it's a fractional number. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you have calculated now is [Electic Flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_flux), Electric flux's dimension is: $kg·m^3·s^{−3}·A^{−1}$

Comment: The difference between flux and number of field lines is discussed in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47624/is-there-is-any-difference-between-electric-flux-psi-and-total-number-of-el?rq=1) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you calculated there is the electric flux generated by a proton, measured at a distance that is *greater* the size of the proton: you have used *e* as the charge, which means that your surface d **S** encloses the whole of the proton (at least within Classical Electrodynamics, where we can assume that the proton has some kind of spherical/definite shape).

The *number of field lines* is not something that has much of a physical meaning.
Basically because there could be an infinite number of field lines through a given patch of surface d **S**. You would need to specify the distance between these field lines, so that you can divide a length (say 10 m) through the separation between each field line (say 1 m) therefore resulting in 10 field lines.
This, however, assumed that the field lines are equally spaced.

Check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107586/does-it-really-make-sense-to-talk-about-field-lines)